# Update ERC-20 Storage slot from Substrate

Tags: substrate-node-template, evm, frontier, erc20

I'm trying to make a PoC (using frontier template) where I should update the `balance` of an EVM ERC-20.
I guess that the steps should be as follows:

1. Calculate the storage slot like this tool does: https://github.com/danforbes/substrate-evm/blob/master/utils/README.md#commands
2. Write the EVM state
3. Commit the State

So, knowing this, I don't know where to start for updating the EVM storage from the Substrate Runtime... and I don't find any resource talking about that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want is to update the amount of supply of your ERC20 token.

The ERC20 token: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol has two functions for that purpose:

- `mint`: Creates `amount` tokens and assigns them to `account`, increasing the total supply.
- `burn`: Destroys `amount` tokens from `account`, reducing the total supply.

You can call this functions via an Extrinsic in your EVM pallet. To check how to interact with an ERC20 token via extrinsics I'd suggest to take a look into the Substrate tutorial: [Access EVM accounts](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/access-evm-accounts/)